# Reading event log from remote machine without passing credentials

Tags: c#, event-log

I am reading the event log of remote machine using following code.

```
EventLog elog = new EventLog(logName, serverName);
```

I tried to access the log of other machine in my network without having access to those machine. I was really surprised that I can read eventlog without having any credential to remote pc.

Please let me know that whether this is default logic or not. I want to ensure that I can access log of any machine that is accessible on my LAN (may be on different domain).

Answer (score 0):

That works because the machines are on your domain and the creds used for the machine running the code work on those machines. If you try to access a machine on another domain it will fail. You'll either have to provide creds, or a simple work around is to run the program as a user in that domain.